# Magento CMS block on footer not working after cache enable

Tags: php, magento, caching, magento-1.9

I'm trying to show a Magento CMS block only one home page footer area, I'm using below code

```
$routeName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); 
$identifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();

if($routeName == 'cms' && $identifier == 'home') {
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_seo')->toHtml();
}
```

This code working perfectly when i disable cache, but after enable cache this shows on all pages, sometimes not display on any pages.

I tried few solutions on stack-overflow but those didn't worked , my Magento version is 1.9.2.4

Anyone know how to fix this issue please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that using action tag inside reference tag  for remove cashes from footer,

This looks like a known bug on Magento 1.9 versions, Thanks for everyone helps me specially Mladen Ilić

```
<reference name="footer">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime"></action>
        <block type="cms/block" name="footer.seo">
            <action method="setBlockId"><value>footer_seo</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use layout handles to conditionally add blocks to layout (probably from your theme's `local.xml`):

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="cms/block" name="footer.seo">
            <action method="setBlockId"><value>footer_seo</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

if you do not have `local.xml`, don't forget to wrap the above code with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    ... layout handle code...
</layout>
```

After that, all you have to do is output your block in footer template:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('footer.seo');
```

This way you will avoid hackish checks in your template.

Best of luck.

Comment: i created a local.xml file on theme layout  folder with above xml codes and added above php codes inside footer.phtml, but i cannot see any output, is there anything should i check, thank you

Comment: @ Suneth Kalhara: Updated answer with local.xml wrapper. :)

Comment: I did exactly above, if i clear cashes and load home page it also shows on other pages, if i clear cashes and a another page first then it don't show on any pages, my site is on http://www.horecadev.nl/test1/ , seems a strange issue :)

Comment: Try adding the layout update (xml) from admin panel (CMS -> Pages -> Your page -> Custom Layout update). That way it should be applied to only one cms page.

Comment: above solution also facing cache issue mate, when u disable  Blocks HTML output above all solutions works great, after enable that, it displays or not. if i open inner page after clear cache it not display on any pages, if i open home page after clear cashe it shows on all pages :(